# How to Drag and Select Files in a JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a `JFileChooser` that I would like to select multiple files from. I want to be able to drag and select multiple files; having the same functionality as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> (think your OS's folder, the highlighted box when you click and move your mouse).

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Files");
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true); 
    // this just lets the user select multiple items with shift and ctrl
```

How do I do this?

**Edit:**

I'm not asking about getting the selected files.

**Edit 2:**

From what I've seen this doesn't seem possible, although those sources are from at latest 2009.